# How to send recurring, custom emails to my users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, email

I have a site with many "channels" customers can subscribe to. I want to send each customer a unique weekly email based on any new content from their subscriptions, plus some suggestions of additional subscriptions. Feels like a very common use-case.

I'm not sure the best approach or service to use here. I could code everything myself and run a recurring job to send the emails. It feels like there should be a service which has a list of my user ids and pings my server for all the custom fields to inject into an email. But I can't find such a service.

Can anyone recommend a best practice for doing this kind of thing? (I'm using RoR on Heroku and have an Mandrill account.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking over your question, it seems that you're looking for the "missing piece of the puzzle" to help you get this setup. So I'll give you some insights that we've found:

---

**[Queuing With Redis & Resque](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque)**

[Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) & [Redis](http://redis.io/) are technologies for handling queuing with web-based applications

Resque is a gem which allows you to host "queues", and process them in the background (with cron jobs & the like). On the Heroku platform, you'll be able to use the [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) to process the queue as-and-when required

Redis is a technology which runs parallel to your application, allowing for the storing of JSON-type data objects (key/value pairs). Heroku has several third-party redis addons you can use, which will get you started & allow you to scale. Redis is best described as "RAM" for your app - allowing you to store a series of data objects that can be used independently to your app's RESTful infrastructure

---

**[Resque Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque)**

[image: Resque RailsCast]

Ryan Bates actually explains the Resque process very well on one of his RailsCasts. I'd check it out & implement the code to get it something down; you can then iterate on top of it later!

I can post live code if you want?

Comment: So you're suggesting adding each user to the queue and pulling them off the queue and sending a single email until the queue is empty? That feels sensible. I guess I was hoping for a SaaS recommendation, but if you think this approach is sensible, I can certainly give it a go.

Comment: Hey Scott, this is a way to do it programmatically -- if you're looking to use some sort of SaaS system, you may wish to check out how to integrate into the API's of the likes of Mailchimp or Aweber.... but you'd still have the problem of scheduling the messages to be sent etc. The problem is that your application contains the data of what to send & when to send, and the challenge is sending that data to the correct service. That's what I think you're having problems with :)

Comment: Cool. You're right. I was hoping there would be some SaaS which could, via some kind of endpoint I would code, fetch all the relevant details before sending the emails. Seems like no one is aware of such a service.